# Java boolean not passing from class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have many classes in Java. I want that if I click on a Radiobutton on Window (my main GUI), that the boolean value is passed to other classes.

Here are how they are "architected".
Here is my class Window:

```
class Window{
    Oscillo parent;
    Graph graph;
    boolean b1=true;
    boolean b2 = false;

    Window(Oscillo parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}//end class
```

Here is my class Graph:

```
   class Graph extends JPanel(){
         Window parent;
          // tried to get my boolean values from Window but nothing worked

         private class SG{
             SG(Graphics g, int id){
             // tried to get my boolean values from Window but nothing worked
          ...
          }//end private class
    }//end class
```

Here is my class Data:

```
    class Data{
        private Oscillo parent;
        // tried to get my boolean values from Window but nothing worked
        Data (Oscillo parent){
          // tried to get my boolean values from Window but nothing worked
        }
        ...
    }//end class
```

Here is my class Oscillo

```
    public class Oscillo implements MessageListener{
        Data data;
        Window window;
        // tried to get my boolean values from Window but nothing worked
        ...
    }//end class
```

I tried several things, super.b1, parent.b1... and so on, but I couldn't get my boolean values passed from one class to the others.

If u could help me to solve my problem, I would be grateful !
Have a nice day !

Tom

Comment: "tried to get my boolean values from Window but nothing worked" - what do you mean by it? You are unable to receive the changed values, compiler error or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expose them to other classes using get methods, as such:

```
class Window{
    Oscillo parent;
    Graph graph;
    boolean b1=true;
    boolean b2 = false;

    Window(Oscillo parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    // I would urge you to choose better names that are more clear
    // for both variables and methods
    boolean getB1() { return b1; }
    boolean getB2() { return b2; }

}//end class
```

And then simply use them to read the values, as such:

```
class Graph extends JPanel(){
     Window parent;

     private class SG{
         SG(Graphics g, int id){
         parent.getB1(); //getting b1's value
      }//end private class
 }//end class
```

And so on...

When you only have `Oscillo` object and you want to access `b1` or `b2` through its' `Window` object, add another get method for Window and then chain these calls together as such:

```
public class Oscillo implements MessageListener{
    Data data;
    Window window;

    //get b1 or b2 by window.getB1() and window.getB2() accordingly

   Window getWindow() { return window; }

}//end class

class Data{
    private Oscillo parent;
    Data (Oscillo parent){
       // might be worth checking if window is not null,
       // depending on your architecture and invariants
       parent.getWindow().getB1();
    }
    ...
}//end class
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you both of you ! I made a mix of your replies and worked !

Answer (score 0):

To me seems like you are trying to work with *static* values from *W* indow (since you say in the title of the question **boolean not passing from *class***). I  am just guessing this. If b1, b2 should be shared between instances of Window class then they (b1, b2) are static. Deeclare static fields as following

```
class Window
{
    public static boolean b1 = true;
    public static boolean b2 = false;
}
```

and access fields as

```
boolean somebool = Window.b1;
```